# Display Div on JQuery Datepicker (Text Field) value selection

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am having trouble getting the right div to display when someone makes a datepicker selection. I noticed when I remove 'readonly' and disable the datepicker, then manually type in the date (In this case 'Friday, 18 December, 2015') it works. But when 'readonly' is enabled and you use the datepicker function to select the date, nothing happens. I need the divs to have the ability to change back and forth depending on which date is selected.

BONUS! I would like to be able to add multiple dates to the java code. However, when I tried `this.value == "Friday, 18 December, 2015", "Saturday, 19 December, 2015"` it triggers the javascript no matter what the input is.

Link - http://jsfiddle.net/u893btef/2/

HTML

```
<label><strong>Delivery Date</strong></label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Datepicker1" style="border-radius:5px; font-family: 'PJFont', sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:14px; margin-bottom:-5px;">
<br>

<div id="Datepicker1_hidden_div1" style="display: block;">
  <label><strong>Delivery Time</strong></label>
  <select name="ChooseTime1" style="border-radius:5px; font-family: sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:14px; margin-bottom:5px">
    <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option>All other options</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="Datepicker1_hidden_div2" style="display: none;">
  <label><strong>Delivery Time</strong></label>
  <select name="ChooseTime1" style="border-radius:5px; font-family: sans-serif; color:#333; font-size:14px; margin-bottom:5px">
    <option selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option>Dec 18th Options</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JAVA

```
 /* Time Select */
 document.getElementById('datepicker').addEventListener('change', function() {
   if (this.value == "Friday, 18 December, 2015") {
     document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div2").style.display = "block",
       document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div1").style.display = "none";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div1").style.display = "block",
       document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div2").style.display = "none";
   }
 });
 /* Datepicker 1 */
 $(function() {
   var array = ["Saturday, 12 December, 2015", "Saturday, 19 December, 2015"]
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     minDate: 3,
     maxDate: 180,
     dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
     changeMonth: true,
     showButtonPanel: true,
     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d MM, yy', date);
       return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
     }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved It

```
 /* Datepicker 1 */
 $(function() {
   var array = ["Saturday, 12 December, 2015", "Saturday, 19 December, 2015"]
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     minDate: 3,
     maxDate: 180,
     dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
     changeMonth: true,
     showButtonPanel: true,
     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
       var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d MM, yy', date);
       return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
     }
   }).on("change", function() {
    if (this.value == "Friday, 18 December, 2015") {
     document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div2").style.display = "block",
       document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div1").style.display = "none";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div1").style.display = "block",
       document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div2").style.display = "none";
   };
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enabled readonly true, you can't use it as selection. So I have given an ulternate option, if you don't like that any user can type, just input via datepicker.

You can find the same jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rg659f4a/

Here is the code.

```
window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('datepicker').addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (this.value == "Friday, 18 December, 2015") {
                document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div2").style.display = "block",
                        document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div1").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div1").style.display = "block",
                        document.getElementById("Datepicker1_hidden_div2").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hi');
        $('#datepicker').keyup(function(e){
                $(this).val('');
        });
    });
    $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response :-) However, I could not get the code you provided to work in jsfiddle or otherwise. The only way it works is if I manually input the date (ie. Friday, 18 December, 2015). It seems to be irrelevant weather or not I have the 'readonly' option attached to the input tag. For whatever reason, when I use the datepicker to select the date it fails to initiate the 'change' function. Here is what I am currently working with - http://jsfiddle.net/u893btef/2/  - You'll notice when you select 'Friday, 18 December, 2015' it fails to initiate.